# Content not shown on some older browsers and mobile devices (SGS3)

Tags: content, mobile

I'm fronting an issue with my newly created website. I'm using Wordpress 3.8 and a custom child theme (Twenty Fourteen).

I've seen a problem, where some mobile phones (like the SGS3)  and some older browsers cannot show the content of posts and pages.

http://www.citizen-science.at/

Samsung Galaxy S3 was one of a few phones which could not display the page. Also some older versions of the Safari browser and some others. It seems as if updating the browser mostly fixes the issue, but I want to support older browsers as well.

Here is an example of how it looks like:

[image: screenshot with missing content part]

Where the white part is, there should be the content of the page, which is just not shown.

**EDIT:**

*Known browsers which are not working:*

- Android Internet (Samsung Galaxy S3, Android 4.3)
- Android Internet (Samsung Galaxy S3 mini, Android 4.1)
- Safari (Desktop Version 5.1.7, Win 8.1)

**EDIT 2:**

I've seen that one subpage of my site is working:

http://www.citizen-science.at/projekte/roadkill/ubersicht/

But others aren't.

Comment: I tried it on my nexus 7. No issues. Check your CSS.

Comment: Strange thing is that rly the content of the pages and posts is just not visible (the text). The login will show up shortly and then disappear again

Comment: Still not working

Comment: You could add more information on which old browsers and exact versions this happens. We need to be able to replicate the issue to find the cause.

Comment: Edited my question. If you are using windows and try with the Safari 5.1.7 version you can face this problem

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your JS. When I disable JS it works. Try removing all js and adding back one after the other to see what causes the issue.

Comment: I tried removing all enqueue scrips from the functions.php but no change. I guess this should get rid of any javascript problems..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is your css. I went into the your CSS and for `.content-area`. I took out the float left and then went into

> line 753

and took out the `display:table`. I am not sure on this theme but if it is using tables I would change it all to div's

```
.footer-sidebar::before, 
.footer-sidebar::after, 
.hentry::before, 
.hentry::after, 
.slider-direction-nav::before, 
.slider-direction-nav::after, 
.contributor-info::before, 
.contributor-info::after, 
.search-box::before, 
.search-box::after, [class*="content"]::before, [class*="content"]::after,
[class*="site"]::before, 
[class*="site"]::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
```

That is what displayed it for me but without the actual code I am only seeing those two things wrong. You do not have to take out the display table  but just take out class content part and you might be fine.

`[class*="content"]::before, [class*="content"]::after,`

I am not 100 percent sure but I know that is where your problem is.

Comment: Cool thing is I do not override this style class in my child theme. This is from the standard theme, but I will give it a try!

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot. Bad thing is this comes from the twentyfourteen theme itself. How should a noob like me get that work? T_T

Comment: I do not understand your question. Just go into wordpress admin panel and then go to appearance. Then go to editor and then go to your stylesheet. Or you can get a plugin that adds the css so that way if you update your theme you do not lose your custom CSS. If you have a custom css file or plugin you can just copy and paste the same CSS but take out the CSS noted above and it should overwrite you default or since you are using a childe theme then just do it in your stylesheet.css.

Comment: Sorry I confused you here. I already got it working but I never was thinking of the problem exisiting in the parent theme already. My knowledge of css is not that good and I wouldn't have been able to solve this on my own. Thanks a lot

Comment: Just glad you got it solved.

Answer (score 1):

At first, I think the problem is more complex and not easy to debug.
But, If you put it at the top I would think it would slow down the loading of the css. Change the position of the fonts. Also you load a lot of font-face with custom fonts, maybe to much for older browser and his memory. Also is it not easy for older browser to load all ressources, mich request. Download the fonts and include with static address in your stylesheet.

Also is it a fine idea to add a fallback font. But a t first play with less fonts and check again.

Also the hint to add the follow source to your `.htaccess`.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

See the full discussion to this hint [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856502/css-font-face-not-working-with-firefox-but-working-with-chrome-and-ie?rq=1).

Currently have a lot of older browsers your problem, see http://browsershots.org/http://www.citizen-science.at/

Comment: If I put it at the top? I don't get it. And also what position of the fonts? What I already tried was removing all font-face tags, but it had no effect at all

Comment: Add a default font to the body element, like `body{font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;` and remove the `@font-face` Syntax, works this?

Comment: No changes, also I would wonder, because the font used in the content is the same like for the navigation (which is showing)

Comment: Hm, Maybe you have a js problem, that a class or inline style, there hide this content? I think is not a font problem, after I read your enhancements on the question. But I can not test on different clients, works always.

Comment: Try Safari for windows. And yeah I have the same problem with testing. Safari does not seem to provide any kind of developer tools..

Comment: But the safari have also the Web Inspector inside, but you must active at first -> Preferences --> Advanced, Active the Checkbox on "Show Develop menu in tool bar". Now you can use the Web Inspector.

Comment: If I debug this in Safari with the Web Inspector I found a problem with the stylesheet. The class `content-area` hafe a float, confused to the other table-statements. If I clear table and floats, it works.